# Enable Auto focus after timer on Nikon D800?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, remote, nikon-d800

I'll start with an apology if everyone knows this but me.

I bought a Nikon D800 about a month ago (adore), but the wireless remote I used for the D7000 is not compatible.  No worries, I'll just shoot a self-portrait using the timer.

However, the camera focuses on the background (absent me) so when I'm in the frame, I'm out of focus.

My question: is there a way to tell the camera to do its auto-focus magic at the conclusion of the timer and right before the frame is snapped? Or will it only focus when I depress the trigger to start the timer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also use a D800, as far as I am aware there is no way to set the camera to focus after the timer - the only method that I could think of would be to either buy a remote release or shoot tethered.

Comment: I bought a remote release and all is well.  thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To do the self-portraits you can use interval timer shooting.

[Menu] [Shooting menu] [Interval timer shooting] (check the manual if you cant find it) [Start time = now] (you waste the first shot but it saves you having to wait a minute) [Interval time 00:00:10 seconds] ( or however long you need between shots ) [Set 5 intervals X 1] ( this will take 5 timed shots 10 seconds apart) [Start = On] Put it on the tripod Hit [OK] and run round the front.

It will focus just before it takes each of 5 shots.

Comment: Works great in my D750 too. I have continuos focus enabled and auto focus points

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this; my D300 works the same way. I usually switch to manual focus and either have a stand-in subject or set a small enough aperture to account for any misfocus. (Finding a stand-in subject is easy, though: use your camera bag, a rock, or even turn around to find anything else at roughly the same distance.)